# Need operator like grep in If else in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

How can I measure when a string contains my word...

I just want if character "Amit" to come in the VAR, I print "Its Amit"...
i.e.  I know operator like ==  but I don't know what is for like "grep"

```
VAR="hello Amit"

if [[ $VAR == Amit ]]
then
  echo "Its Amit"
else
  echo "Its not Amit"
fi
```

Comment: I think chepner gave that answer you need. **BUT** I think the answer on how to use `grep` in an if/else statement is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48536)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` is the operator you want. The RHS does not have to be a fixed string; it can also be an extended glob, which is different from but equivalent in power to a regular expression.

```
if [[ $VAR == *Amit* ]];  # will succeed for any string containing Amit as a substring.
```

You can also use `~=` if you want to use a regular expression. Since the match is not explicitly anchored to the beginning or ending of the string, you can simply use

```
if [[ $VAR ~= Amit ]]
```

Comment: perfect, thanks work >if [[ $VAR == *Amit* ]];, didnt work > if [[ $VAR ~= Amit ]], sort my problem by 1st line..